# How can I replace a string with a variable?

Tags: jquery

I have:

```
<p  class="replace_me">Here is my text to replace</p>
```

and in jQuery:

```
var newtext=something created dynamically;
```

I want to replace the whole paragraph with the value of the variable. Replacing the paragraph with a string seems to be easy just using replaceWith(). But as far as I know, that method only offers to replace some text with other text. As the content I want to use is created dynamically, this method is not useful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: <div id="someId"><p class="replace_me">Here is my text to replace</p></div> then you can say $(".someId").html("Something created dynamically"); This will replace the whole paragraph.

Comment: `.text()` will change the text, use `.html()` if you want to keep any html (and don't want it encoded)

Comment: @ErhardDinhobl Be careful with your selectors `$("#someId")`, not `$(".someId")` :).

Comment: Yes. That's right. My fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try it using jquery :

```js
var newtext = "something created dynamically";
$(".replace_me").html(newtext);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="replace_me">Here is my text to replace</p>
```